# I want to declare the values of the objects within the class and only call the keys when Im declaring a new class. What could I do?

Tags: javascript, class, object, key-value

This is what Ive done so far.

```
class PriceCalc {
  constructor(Obj) {
    this.parts = Object.keys(Obj);
    this.cost =
      "$" +
      Object.values(Obj)
        .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
        .toFixed(2);
    this.retail =
      "$" +
      (
        Object.values(Obj).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) +
        Object.values(Obj).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) * 1.75
      ).toFixed(2);
    this.quote = qt + this.retail;
  }
}
var total = new PriceCalc({
  Motherboard: 520.99,
  RAM: 250.4,
  SSD: 500.8,
  HDD: 400.66,
  Case: 375.5,
  Monitor: 600.75,
  Keyboard: 100.99,
  Mouse: 25.5
});
console.log(total.parts);
console.log(total.cost);
console.log(total.retail);
console.log(total.quote);
```

What Id like to achieve is having the values declared within the class then only call something like

```
var total = new PriceCalc({Motherboard, RAM, SSD, HDD});
```

And return the combined value of the specified parts, which in this case would be $1,672.85, for this.cost

Comment: Sounds like you need a normal function, not a class.

Comment: Part of the task that I am trying to complete, requires the use of the class. The only thing I can think of is writing the function after the constructor, within the class

Comment: Writing it as a function to access the classes properties sounds like a good idea. By the way, what is `qt`? It seems to be never defined.

Comment: qt was declared in another part of the overall code, its just a string that I want to call multiple times, rather than writing it multiple times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Put default values to class properties.
2. Pass strings of properties that you want to get.
3. Use `this[b]` to get object property
4. Ensure you sum up numbers and not strings: `qt + this.quote` would give you string concatenation instead of arithmetical operation.

```js
class PriceCalc {
  Motherboard = 520.99;
  RAM = 250.40;
  SSD = 500.80;
  HDD = 400.66;
  Case = 375.50;
  Monitor = 600.75;
  Keyboard = 100.99;
  Mouse = 25.50;
  
  parts = []
  cost = '$0'
  retail = '$0'
  quote = '0'

  constructor(Obj) {
    this.parts = Obj.join(',');
    this.cost = "$" + (Obj.reduce((a, b) => a + this[b], 0).toFixed(2));
    this.retail = "$" + ((Obj.reduce((a, b) => a + this[b], 0) + (Obj.reduce((a, b) => a + this[b], 0) * 1.75)).toFixed(2));
    //this.quote = qt + this.retail;
  }
}

var total = new PriceCalc([
  'Motherboard',
  'RAM',
  'SSD',
  'HDD'
]);

console.log(total.parts)
console.log(total.cost)
console.log(total.retail)
console.log(total.quote)
```

Comment: Also add the $ when displaying, not when calculating

Comment: These parts seem to be redundant   parts = []
  cost = '$0'
  retail = '$0'
  quote = '0'